# WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'OCR'; the following exception was raised: No module named 'OCR'

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have Problems to let 'autodoc' read a Python File ( OCR.py ).
I have no Idea what the Problem could be. Maybe someone can help.
Thank you a lot for reading and maybe advising!

```
Folder Structure:

AutoQA
  Docu
    _build
    QALibs
      Automation.rst
    conf.py
    index.rst
    make.bat
  QALibs
    Automation
      Automation.py
      OCR.py
```

If I move the `OCR.py` File to `AutoQA/QAlibs/OCR` then it works. But I don't want do that because it belongs to the Automation Folder.

---

```
Automation.rst:

Automation
==========

.. automodule:: Automation
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :inherited-members:

.. automodule:: OCR
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :inherited-members:
```

---

```
conf.py:

import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../QALibs'))

project = 'AutoQA'

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc'
]

html_theme = "sphinx_rtd_theme"
```

---

```
index.rst:

.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 4
    :caption: QALibs Documentation

    QALibs/Automation
```

---

```
OCR.py ( Excerpt ):

'''
Module **OCR** provides Tools for Screen Reading.
Uses `Tesseract OCR`_.

.. _Tesseract OCR: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract
'''
import pytesseract, pyautogui, sys, cv2
sys.path.append('../..')
from QALibs.Automation import Automation
from QALibs.Log import Log


@staticmethod
def findText(text, getRightPosition=False):
...
```

I also thought it could be because of the `sys.path.apend` here. But it doesn't make any difference if with this Line or without.

---

```
Sphinx 'make html' Output after 'make clean':

Removing everything under '_build'...
Running Sphinx v2.1.2
making output directory... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 23 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 23 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] py-modindex
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'OCR'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'OCR'
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] py-modindex
generating indices... genindex py-modindex
writing additional pages... searchc:\users\dschiller.iet\appdata\local\programs\python\
  python37-32\lib\
  site-packages\sphinx_rtd_theme\search.html:20: RemovedInSphinx30Warning: 
  To modify script_files in the theme is deprecated. Please insert a 
  <script> tag directly in your theme instead.
  {{ super() }}

copying images... [100%] AutoQA\../Images/AutoQA/Initializer.png
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en) ... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 9 warnings.

The HTML pages are in _build\html.
```

Comment: It looks like `OCR` is a submodule of the `Automation` package. Then I would expect `.. automodule:: Automation.OCR` to work. Or If `QALibs` is the top-level package, use `.. automodule:: QALibs.Automation.OCR`, with `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('..'))`.

Comment: I changed everything like your first guess (``Automation.OCR``) and get the Error in Sphinx: ``D:\Work\Coding\Python\Scrum\AutoQA\QALibs\Automation\OCR.py:docstring of Automation.OCR.findText:11: WARNING: Unexpected indentation.``. Have no Idea which indention is meant there. Line 11 is empty. If I use ``QALibs.Automation.OCR`` and ``('..')`` then I get this Error in Sphinx: ``WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'Automation.OCR' from module 'QALibs'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'QALibs'``.

Comment: The ``Automation.OCR`` did it. The ``Unexpected indentation`` happened because of wrong used decorator ``@staticmethod``. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `mzjn's` Comment this is the Solution:

```
Automation.rst:

Automation
==========

.. automodule:: Automation.Automation  # << The Module also need the Package Name
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :inherited-members:

# .. automodule:: OCR  # << This is invalid; The Module also need the Package Name
.. automodule:: Automation.OCR
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :inherited-members:
```

```
OCR.py ( Excerpt ):

'''
Module **OCR** provides Tools for Screen Reading.
Uses `Tesseract OCR`_.

.. _Tesseract OCR: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract
'''
import pytesseract, pyautogui, sys, cv2
sys.path.append('../..')
sys.path.append('..')  # << Is needed; Otherwise 'QALibs' not found within Sphinx
from QALibs.Automation import Automation
from QALibs.Log import Log


# @staticmethod  # <<< This is invalid here; Only useable in Classes
def findText(text, getRightPosition=False):
...
```

---

Instead of the `sys.path.append('..')` Line one also could use a `__init__.py` File withing the `Automation` Folder.

```
QALibs/Automation/__init__.py

import sys
sys.path.append('..')  # Used for Sphinx
```